# Php token on first occurrence only

Tags: php, string, tokenize

I have string like this value1,234,1,2,8. What I need is to break into piece that is value1 and 234,1,2,8. I can you explode but it will break everything where it finds comma. What is the best solution in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

For example:

```
$string = "1,234,1,2,8";
$first = "";
$second = "";
$pos = strpos($string, ",");
if ($pos === false) {
    // no comma found
} else {
    $first = substr($string, 0, $pos);
    $second = substr($string, $pos + 1);
}
```

Comment: perfect this works well. thank you. What does the first pos suppose to give a boolean is it ?

Comment: Check out the documentation on the return value of `strpos()`.